# XrayWrapper error (value is callable) when overwriting prototype method in Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

I'd like to monitor access to certain methods of the browser's built-in objects from a Firefox add-on. The sample code included below largely works, except when one of the method arguments is a function. Then, I receive the following XrayWrapper error:

> XrayWrapper denied access to property 0 (reason: value is callable).
>   See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Xray_vision for more
>   information. Note that only the first denied property access from a
>   given global object will be reported.

I don't understand why an XrayWrapper error would throw, as the prototype instrumented is an object in the `unsafeWindow` (page-script) scope. The content-script used for instrumentation is:

```
function logCalls(object, objectName, methodName) {
  var originalMethod = object[methodName];
  object[methodName] = function () {
    console.log(objectName + "." + methodName, "was called");
    originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

// 1. Works (expected)
logCalls(unsafeWindow.RTCPeerConnection.prototype,
        "unsafeWindow.RTCPeerConnection", "createDataChannel");

// 2. Throws XrayWrapper Error (unexpected)
logCalls(unsafeWindow.RTCPeerConnection.prototype,
        "unsafeWindow.RTCPeerConnection", "createOffer");
```

A sample page-script:

```
var PeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;
var connection = new PeerConnection({iceServers: []}, {optional: [{RtpDataChannels: !0}]});

// 1. Method call recorded
connection.createDataChannel("", {reliable: !1});

// 2. Method call recorded but causes XrayWrapper error
connection.createOffer(function(a) {
    connection.setLocalDescription(a)
}, function(err) {})
```

For (1), the instrumentation works as expected. The call to createDataChannel logs to the console and succeeds in creating a dataChannel.

For (2), the instrumentation successfully logs to console. However, line 5 of the content-script (`originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);`) causes the XrayWrapper error above due to the argument list containing a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should give any method assigned into a different security context the [exportFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.exportFunction) treatment.

That may not be sufficient though, since the method body itself is still executed in the privileged context which means any arguments it receives will also be xray wrappers. Passing them back to the less privileged scope, especially through arcane magic like `apply` and the `arguments` object may not do what you would expect it to. Additional xray unwrapping or using rest parameters and .call instead may be necessary.

In cases like these it may be easier to `eval()` the call-interception logic into the target scope and only export the the logging function called by the interception-wrapper. That way there will not be any unprivileged -> privileged -> unprivileged transition for the arguments, the `this` or return values and only the log call will cross a security boundary.

Since eval is discouraged by addon review guidelines you also may want to consult the reviewers on that approach.

Comment: I attempted to implement solutions that add the additional xray unwrapping as you suggested, but couldn't seem to fix the issue. I instead decided to take the eval approach, which proved much easier. My extension is for testing only, so I don't need to worry about reviews. Thank you!